# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (19,20) (20,19)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, wavelet

I'm trying to implement a wavelet fusion strategy using Python 3 and I have run into an error.

Here's what I have tried:

1. looking through similar problems on StackOverflow

Here's the code that generates the error:

```
    if (method == 'mean'):
        cooef = (cooef1 + cooef2) / 2
    elif (method == 'min'):
        cooef = np.minimum(cooef1,cooef2)
    elif (method == 'max'):
        cooef = np.maximum(cooef1,cooef2)
    else:
        cooef = []
```

Comment: Kindly post the error as well.

Comment: Which line?  What's the shape of the two arrays?  Have tou read enough numpy basics to know what `broadcasting` means?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
cooef1 = np.random.randint(0,10,(19,20))
cooef2 = np.random.randint(0,10,(20,19))
np.maximum(cooef1,cooef2.T)
```